# Error in SQL statement (using JOIN, LIKE and IN)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to execute this SQL statement:

```
SELECT B.CardType, Count(*) as TotalSales
 FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.CreditCard B
 ON A.CreditCardId=B.CreditCardId
 WHERE B.CardType like ('%Vista%') 
 IN ExpMonth=10 AND ExpYear=2006
 GROUP BY B.CardType
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near
>   the keyword 'IN'.

Can anybody please explain why and how to solve it?

Comment: Please try at least googling for SQL syntax before asking. First result for "SQL IN": http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: What do you think the `IN` keyword does?

Answer (score 1):

you missed a condition operator(`AND/OR`). It should rather be

```
WHERE B.CardType like '%Vista%'
AND ExpMonth=10
AND ExpYear=2006
```

You should move those conditions to `JOIN ON` clause instead like

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.CreditCard B
 ON A.CreditCardId=B.CreditCardId
 AND B.CardType like ('%Vista%') 
 WHERE A.ExpMonth=10 
 AND A.ExpYear=2006
 GROUP BY B.CardType
```